# How to save history from a list result coming form an API

Tags: flutter

I´m using a search delegate to give place suggestions i get from an API(mapbox)

when i put a letter down the searchField show the suggestions for that location.
then when y pressed on the location i want, it navigates to another page and show information.

my question is: how i do save that place where i pressed, and show later in history

THIS IS MY SEARCH DELEGATE

```
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    if (query.isEmpty) {
      return _emptyContainer();
    }

    final mapBoxSearch = Provider.of<MapBoxService>(context, listen: false);

    mapBoxSearch.getSuggestionByQuery(query);

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: mapBoxSearch.suggestedCity,
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<Feature>> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return _emptyContainer();

        final featureMethod = snapshot.data!;


        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: featureMethod.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _CityItem(featureMethod[index]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _CityItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Feature city;

  const _CityItem(this.city);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   

    return ListTile(
      leading: const CircleAvatar(
        child: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.mountainCity),
      ),
      title: Text(city.placeName),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'founded', arguments: city);
      },
    );
  }
}




THIS IS WHERE I GET THE SUGGESTIONS... 


STREAM TO COMUNICATE WITH SEARCH DELEGATE 

  final StreamController<List<Feature>> _suggestedCityStreamController =
      new StreamController.broadcast();

  Stream<List<Feature>> get suggestedCity =>
      this._suggestedCityStreamController.stream;

//API CALL

  weatherHeader() {
    return {'access_token': _apiKey, 'limit': _limit, 'language': _language};
  }

  Future<List<Feature>> getPlaces(String cityName) async {
    final uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl,
        '/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + cityName + '.json', weatherHeader());

    final resp = await http.get(uri);

    final mapBoxResp = mapBoxResponseFromMap(resp.body);

    return mapBoxResp.features;
  }

//GET SUGGESTION METHOD 


 void getSuggestionByQuery(String searchTerm) {
    debouncer.value = '';
    debouncer.onValue = (value) async {
      // print('Hay valor : $value');

      final results = await this.getPlaces(value);
      this._suggestedCityStreamController.add(results);
    };
    final timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 200), (_) {
      debouncer.value = searchTerm;
    });
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 201)).then((_) => timer.cancel());
  }
```

I know with sharedPreferences can save anything...

what I don't know is how to catch the argument where I click in the list of results brought by the api